# Parse a virus scan result on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to parse a virus scan result on Ubuntu. Command line:

```
root@pc:/bin# /opt/eset/esets/sbin/esets_scan --clean-mode=None /home/majid/Bureau/1.exe

ESET Command-line scanner, version 4.0.93, (C) 1992-2013 ESET, spol. s r.o.
Module loader, version 1072 (20180813), build 1118
Module perseus, version 1549.3 (20190326), build 2010
Module scanner, version 19107 (20190329), build 40871
Module archiver, version 1285 (20190313), build 1377
Module advheur, version 1192 (20190204), build 1173
Module cleaner, version 1183 (20190305), build 1269

Command line: --clean-mode=None /home/majid/Bureau/1.exe 

Scan started at:   dim. 05 mai 2019 00:52:01 CEST
name="/home/majid/Bureau/1.exe", threat="a variant of MSIL/Kryptik.QME trojan", action="", info=""

Scan completed at: dim. 05 mai 2019 00:52:01 CEST
Scan time:         0 sec (0:00:00)
Total:             files - 1, objects 1
Infected:          files - 1, objects 1
Cleaned:           files - 0, objects 0
```

What I want? Check if `threat=xxxxx` exist, if yes return only type like `a variant of MSIL/Kryptik.QME trojan` else return `clean`.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU grep you can do sth like this:

```
/opt/eset/esets/sbin/esets_scan --clean-mode=None /home/majid/Bureau/1.exe |
  grep -Po 'threat="\K[^"]*' || echo clean
```

If there is a line (or lines) containing `threat="` it will output everything until next doublequote. Otherwise, it will print `clean`.

Note that if your virus scanner somehow fails above command will say `clean` anyway, if it's a problem leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{t="clean"} match($0,/threat="([^"]+)/,a){t=a[1]; exit} END{print t}' file
a variant of MSIL/Kryptik.QME trojan
```

With any awk in any shell in any UNIX box:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{t="clean"} match($0,/threat="[^"]+/){t=substr($0,RSTART+8,RLENGTH-8); exit} END{print t}' file
a variant of MSIL/Kryptik.QME trojan
```